# What should I do if my Android Studio's empty activity is not generating the layout file?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, installation, development-environment

I am not getting any layout(.xml) file while creating an empty activity on android studio. It is said to be created on its own but I can not find the activity_main.xml; It was alright for the first project that I made and it's somehow not working now.

I have tried every thing from reinstalling the app to deleting old projects. I tried to initiate other activities ,they all are working fine,but its a specific problem with empty activity, also I am not getting any option to choose my language; though it is creating a .kt file but the logo appears different from my first project. It would be of great help if anyone could provide a good advice.

Answer (score 4):

In current version of Android Studio, New Android Activity dialog -> *Empty Activity* will create a Activity building the UI with [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose), you have to write composable functions to describe the UI just in the *YourNewActivity.kt* file and without any xml file.

If you are trying to build traditional View system (which using the XML file to build UI and findViewById something), you should choose *Empty Views Activity* from the New Android Activity dialog.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. It is now working properly. I initially thought that empty views activity and empty activity were somehow the same.

Comment: @aashutosh-chahal It's glad to know that it working properly now. If it solve your question, you could _acccept_ my answer. And FYI: Jetpack Compose is a declarative UI framework by Google, after you more familiar with ⌘ View System of Android (which you're trying to defining UI with XML files) you can try declarative framework which in the question is Jetpack Compose. Other declarative framework are well-known too: for example the Flutter from Google which can cross platform, and SwiftUI in Apple developing.

Answer (score 0):

**Please select generate layout file checkbox when you are creating empty activity and i also attach screen short please check**